# Installed Java SE Development Kit, but can't use the command javac

Tags: java, macos, class, terminal

I've just installed the Java SE Development Kit from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk10-downloads-4416644.html

I've created a test java file, to make into a Java class and run - the code is the following:

```
public class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

I then saved this as Hello.java and fired up Terminal (i'm on Mac OSX).

I simply type in:

```
javac Hello.java
```

and it returns the following error message:

```
-bash: javac: command not found
```

If anyone knows why and could help me fix the issue that'd be fantastic.

Comment: what does `cd /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/` show?

Comment: Have you tried to reboot your system so that the environment variables are updated? (I have no idea if that is necessary on MacOS but it certainly won't hurt)

Comment: cd /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/ executes, but just leaves me with a line saying: `JavaVirtualMachines _myusername_$`

Answer (score 1):

**Download the right option.** According to the download link, you're using an Oracle JDK. As a macOS user, you should choose the option `dk-10.0.1_osx-x64_bin.dmg` to download.

**Ensure JDK 10 is installed.** By default, Oracle JDK is installed in system directory `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/`. Browse it and check if there's a sub-directory called `jdk-10.jdk`:

```
$ ls /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/
jdk-10.jdk       jdk-11.jdk       jdk-9.0.4.jdk    jdk1.8.0_131.jdk
```

**Check Java Control Panel.** Go to "System Preferences" > "Java" to check the Java version installed.

**Check the PATH variable.** Ensure `/usr/bin/` is included in it.

```
$ type javac
javac is /usr/bin/javac
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin
               ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your `%PATH%` variable. Your `%PATH%` variable must have path to the `bin` directory in your JDK's installation directory. The PATH variable allows you to access certain files without having to specify their full path, you can check how to add JDK to your PATH [here](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml). If you do not want to mess with it, all you have to do is either `cd` into `bin` directory of your JDK installation or always specify the full path to `javac`, the choice is yours.

Comment: Any idea how to do this? I'm a complete amateur at this stuff.